angular test issue with snackbar
For angular material snackbar I just use the official example and write unit test for the component.
In the test,I use loader with documentRootLoader and MarSnackbarHarness to check whether the snack bar display,it passed. But if I add the duration parameter to the open function,it will can’t find the snackbar element.
Anyone could explain why it can’t get the element and how can I check the display of snack bar element?

please share the minimal reproducible code for checking, working example would be great

Sorry, you could see the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/u18cbk?file=src%2Fexample%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.spec.ts

It seems snackbar requires animations to work, might be due to the delay animation (not sure). The solution is to add provideAnimations to the providers array of the TestBed.
...
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      SnackBarOverviewExample,
      MatSnackBarModule,
    ],
    providers: [
      provideAnimations(),
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
  ...

Stackblitz Demo

Hello, I faced another issue, when I use fakeAsync and tick to assert the snackbar will close it won’t work, could you help check why it is not working? Code
